# Creating a RESTful link in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller called `classroom` and a method called `courses`. The `courses` takes a student param i.e `params[:student]`

```
<%= link_to track_name, classroom_courses_path(:student => "JoeBloggs") %>
```

This will make the link `/classroom/courses?student=JoeBloggs`

However I need the link to be:

`/classroom/courses/JoeBloggs`

How do I amend my code to make this happen?

Comment: What does your route file look like? Also how are your relations structured? Classroom has many courses, courses has many students?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via routes:

```
get 'classroom/courses/:student' => 'classroom#cources', :as => 'get_student_cources'
```

Depending on where you put this route, your _path will be different, so you should `rake routes | grep get_student_cources` to find out exact path name. Then use it in your app:

```
<%= link_to track_name, get_student_cources_path("JoeBloggs".parameterize) %>
```

Note: You should parameterize student name to escape possible characters that will break URL.